# next js 13.3 / Module parse failed: Octal literal in strict mode

Tags: next.js

```
Module parse failed: Octal literal in strict mode.
import { createProxy } from "next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/module-proxy"
```

This error appeared after update 13.3. When creating a client component in the app directory. "use client"

Someone was able to fix it, or do I need to wait for an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem, what I did is change nextJS version, cause nextJS 13.3 have some problems with "use client" functionality, you can do these steps to do the same (it worked for me):

1. Go to your "package.json" and search for "next=x.x" and then change it for another version, in my case I changed it for "next=13.2.4".
2. Then save it and close it.
3. Go to your terninal, inside your project (same level as your package.json).
4. Type "npm install" or "yarn install" depend what you use.

Done, now you're using nextJS at version 13.2.4, and you'll be able to use now "use client". Hope that helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

I saw similar issues on other websites. Some said it may be due to "use client".
In my case, I did the following:

Octal error:

```
export default function Navbar() {}
```

No error:

```
function Navbar() {}
export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm studying next 13 recently apparently version 13.3 has some problem with "use client" use version 13.2.4, this version is working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).